# Cleanest way to create a Guava Multimap from a Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream, guava

I have a `List<Foo>` and want a `Multimap<String, Foo>` where we've grouped the `Foo`'s by their `getId()` function.

I am using Java 8 and its almost awesome in that you can do:

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
Map<String, List<Foo>> foosById = foos.stream().collect(groupingBy(Foo::getId));
```

However, I have a good amount of code that wants a `MultiMap<String, Foo>` so this doesnt save me anything and I'm back to using a for-loop to create my `Multimap`. Is there a nice "functional" way that I am missing?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the other question is indexing the Foo's by a property of theirs that is an arrays (Tags) instead of a property with a single value (id)

Comment: As of Guava 21.0, there is a builtin [Multimaps#toMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#toMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-) and [flatteningToMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#flatteningToMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-) methods that return collectors.

Comment: Voting to reopen, as this is not a duplicate of the linked question.  This one is a straightforward use of the API (as mentioned in the accepted answer), while the other is more about transforming and flat mapping the values and not really about the actual collection itself.

Comment: @DanielBickler Now that answers can be posted again since this question has been re-opened, I've expanded your comment into a full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68443128/1108305

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can just use the Guava [`Multimaps`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) factory:

```java
ImmutableMultimap<String, Foo> foosById = Multimaps.index(foos, Foo::getId);
```

or wrap a call to [`Multimaps.index`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-) with a `Collector<T, A, R>` interface (shown below, in an unoptimized naive implementation).

```java
Multimap<String, Foo> collect = foos.stream()
        .collect(MultimapCollector.toMultimap(Foo::getId));
```

and the `Collector`:

```java
public class MultimapCollector<T, K, V> implements Collector<T, Multimap<K, V>, Multimap<K, V>> {

    private final Function<T, K> keyGetter;
    private final Function<T, V> valueGetter;

    public MultimapCollector(Function<T, K> keyGetter, Function<T, V> valueGetter) {
        this.keyGetter = keyGetter;
        this.valueGetter = valueGetter;
    }

    public static <T, K, V> MultimapCollector<T, K, V> toMultimap(Function<T, K> keyGetter, Function<T, V> valueGetter) {
        return new MultimapCollector<>(keyGetter, valueGetter);
    }

    public static <T, K, V> MultimapCollector<T, K, T> toMultimap(Function<T, K> keyGetter) {
        return new MultimapCollector<>(keyGetter, v -> v);
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<Multimap<K, V>> supplier() {
        return ArrayListMultimap::create;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Multimap<K, V>, T> accumulator() {
        return (map, element) -> map.put(keyGetter.apply(element), valueGetter.apply(element));
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Multimap<K, V>> combiner() {
        return (map1, map2) -> {
            map1.putAll(map2);
            return map1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Multimap<K, V>, Multimap<K, V>> finisher() {
        return map -> map;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return ImmutableSet.of(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Multimaps.index` returns an *immutable* `Multimap`, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Agree, multimap itself is immutable, but it does NOT mean the objects contained in them automatically are. If we can get a reference to an object in an immutable collection, then there's nothing to stop us changing any mutable state on that object. So for some use-case, Multimaps.index is still good. My 2 cents.

Comment: An immutable multimap is exactly what you should want in most cases.

Comment: I wrote an ImmutableMultimapCollector: https://medium.com/@robertmassaioli/an-immutablemultimapcollector-for-guava-3f141f9040f#.m18fnmgwo

Comment: In addition to being immutable, it's worth noting that `Multimaps.index` returns a `ListMultimap`.  If you want a `SetMultimap`, you'll need another step to convert that value if you use `Multimaps.index`, e.g.: `ImmutableSetMultimap.copyOf(Multimaps.index(foos, Foo::getId))`.

Comment: All these are based on an existing map, which would require two iterations. One to create the original list and then iterate on it to create the grouping. Is there not a way to add to a map that will group on the go?

Answer (score 22):

Guava 21.0 introduced several methods that return [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) instances which will convert a `Stream` into a `Multimap` grouped by the result of applying a function to its elements.  These methods are:

| Method | Result |
| --- | --- |
| [`ImmutableListMultimap.toImmutableListMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html#toImmutableListMultimap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) | [`ImmutableListMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html#toImmutableListMultimap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) |
| [`ImmutableSetMultimap.toImmutableSetMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.html#toImmutableSetMultimap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) | [`ImmutableSetMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.html) |
| [`Multimaps.toMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#toMultimap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier)) | Value returned by the provided [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html) |

```java
ImmutableListMultimap<String, Foo> foosById = foos.stream().collect(
        ImmutableListMultimap.toImmutableListMultimap(
                Foo::getId, Function.identity()));
```

```java
ImmutableSetMultimap<String, Foo> foosById = foos.stream().collect(
        ImmutableSetMultimap.toImmutableSetMultimap(
                Foo::getId, Function.identity()));
```

```java
HashMultimap<String, Foo> foosById = foos.stream().collect(
        Multimaps.toMultimap(
                Foo::getId, Function.identity(), HashMultimap::create)
);
```

Comment: All these are based on an existing map, which would require two iterations. One to create the original list and then iterate on it to create the grouping. Is there not a way to add to a map that will group on the go?

Comment: @mjs The question was about creating a `Multimap` from a `Stream`, which these do directly.  Yes, you can definitely create a `HashMultimap` of the desired type and then add to it (for mutable maps), or create an immutable map containing the desired entries using a builder or a creator method.  See Guava's guide on this, [NewCollectionTypesExplained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap).