# Use of streams to store multimap

Tags: java-stream, multimap

I want to store items in multimap. For that I am using

```
Multimap<Integer, EmployeeClass> mapEmp = result.stream()
                        .collect(toMultimap(result::getdepartment ,result, ArrayListMultimap::create) );
```

This is not working. How can I use streams (in General) to add items in multimap?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cleanest way to create a Guava Multimap from a Java 8 stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003542/cleanest-way-to-create-a-guava-multimap-from-a-java-8-stream)

Comment: @YassinHajaj... I'll try it out and let you know. :)